# Detect if an object stores state or can be shared

Tags: java, caching, reflection, reference

I'm implementing an object cache:

```
void cache(String request_type, String request_id, ProcessingStrategy request_strategy) 
{ 
    if (no_state(request_strategy) == true)
       map.put(request_type, request_strategy);
    else
       map.put(request_id, request_strategy); //no chance of keyspace collision
}

ProcessingStrategy lookup(String request_type, String request_id)
{
    ProcessingStrategy request_strategy = map.get(request_type);
    if (request_strategy == null) return map.get(request_id)
    else return request_strategy;
}
```

This scheme of sharing objects implementing `interface ProcessingStrategy` across all requests of a particular type will only work if there is no state being stored in the concrete class.

**How do I write the `no_state` method?**

I am thinking checking if all member fields are `final` using Reflection will suffice:

```
for(Field f : request_strategy.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
    if(!Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()))
        return false;
//even if all fields are final;
//how to check that they are not being initialized with differently in the ProcessingStrategy constructor?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're attempting to do (detect mutability of an arbitrary object), I don't think can be done.  Even if it could, through some reflective acrobatics, it still seems a bad idea.

If you control the `ProcessingStrategy` interface or its implementors, perhaps you can use a method, `isStateless()`, or a subinterface, `StatelessProcessingStrategy` which are, by convention, shareable across requests.

Comment: Many genuinely thread-safe, immutable objects have some internal, mutable, "lazily computed" state -- e.g. String.hashCode().

Comment: I'll go with StatelessProcessingStrategy

Answer (score 2):

> I am thinking checking if all member fields are final using Reflection will suffice

It won't.

What if the member field is a final reference to an array or collection.  How can you tell if the array / collection is part of the object state (by design) or not?

The problem is that the Java language provides no way to say where the conceptual boundaries of the design objects are ... so there's nothing to interogate reflectively.

A better idea might be to rely on the clients of your code to "declare" that classes are stateful or non-stateful using custom annotations.

Comment: I was pretty sure it was impossible but needed a second opinion, thanks.